# Copying Items from Sheet 1 and pasting to sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

Range of object error coming up with this code (error 1004).
Can you please help me out debug this?

```
Sub ggg()

    last = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    last1 = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last, 2)).Copy Sheet2.Range(last1 + 1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: (a) you have unqualified `Cells` objects in your last line - they are probably meant to be `Sheet1.Cells` (b) the `Range` property does not accept two parameters which are numeric - is that meant to be `Sheet2.Cells(last1 + 1, 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this doesn't find the last used cell

```
last = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
last1 = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
```

It sometimes jumps to the very last cell of Excel and then you try to add `+1` here

```
Sheet2.Range(last1 + 1, 1)
```

which fails because there is no additional cell after the very last cell.

Use

```
last = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last1 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

to find the last used cell.

Second problem is that `Sheet2.Range(last1 + 1, 1)` [doesn't accept two numeric parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) (as YowE3K pointed out in the comment). Therefore use `Sheet2.Cells(last1 + 1, 1)`

VBA Best Practices include (1) to never assume the worksheet and (2) use fully qualified cell objects.

Comment: @YowE3K sure you are right, didn't see that yet. Fixed my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks a ton. I have used the below coding as you mentioned ,still I am getting error

Sub ggg()

    last = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    last1 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last, 2)).Copy Sheet2.Cells(last1 + 1, 1)
    

End Sub

Comment: @SouraChatterjee "I am getting error" is not a qualified error message. If you don't tell *which* error you get nobody can help you.